# What is the LaTeX command for "em dash" (—)?

Tags: symbols, punctuation

I am trying to insert the symbol in the title of the question, which I copied from a PDF article, but it appears as space in the output file. What is the corresponding LaTeX command?

Comment: Probably the input encoding does not have the em dash configured. I'd suggest to use the solution by Keks Dose.

Comment: Also see [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: If my typographer's memory serves me, the first item in the list above is not known as a hyphen but as a *tee dash*. (Or was it simply a matter of tee spaces, en spaces, and em spaces?) Gosh, I used to all know this back when I did actual physical typography...

Comment: Just came here for an answer, since the em dash looked like a space in the PDF previewer I was using.  Turns out the font just had a very thin line for a dash.  I embiggened the previewer, and voila!--there were the em dashes!  In case someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 400, accepted):

The LaTeX command for such a line are three small ones: `---`

Comment: Alternatively `\textemdash`.

Comment: Or use Xe/LuaLaTeX and just type `—`.

Comment: @Caramdir: You don't even have to use Xe/LuaLaTeX; pdfLaTeX with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` works fine for directly inputting an em dash `—`.

Comment: This is not a LaTeX command and it doesn't work universally: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=xetex_faq#ligs

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka Yes, you are right, it's not a LaTeX command. But in ten years of using LaTeX it never failed, so thank you for your comment, but for most of the readers the answer contains what they need, doesn't it?

Comment: @KeksDose Not for anyone using unicode fonts, as most of us do now.

Comment: If you're using Unicode fonts (i.e. you're using XeTeX or LuaTeX), just add ``Ligatures = TeX`` as a font option. You need that for any of the typical TeX conversions such as `````, ``'``, ``--`` etc.

Comment: does `\textemdash` work in comments, though?  test: $\textemdash$

Comment: This does not work for math mode. I am using `\mbox{---}`. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: @Caramdir how do i "type" that?

Comment: @user313032 On Linux with a german layout of the keyboard I get all the dashes using the dash key and "AltGr" or dash key and "AltGr" plus Ctrl.

Answer (score 282):

The question has already been answered, but for completeness' sake:

- Hyphen: `-`
- En-dash: `--`
- Em-dash: `---`

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, I like to call the first one (`-`) a _hyphen_, because it's usually not used as a dash. In Unicode it's called _Minus-hyphen_, that's the one normal keyboards enter. (Unicode also has a symbol called [_Hyphen_](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?page=02&subpage=0&hilite=02010).

Comment: Donald Knuth, for completeness, adds the fourth one, the mathematical minus sign, $-$.  (The TEXbook, page 4.)

Comment: Using xelatex (`XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9)`) this does not work. Two hyphens just come out as two hyphens.

Comment: @Marcin Add ``Ligatures = TeX`` as an option when you load your font.

Comment: @Sverre Did you get that from my answer?

Comment: @Marcin: No. Your answer was at the bottom, so didn't see it until after I had commented. Anyways, ``Ligatures = TeX`` is as I understand the standard way of using traditional LaTeX conversions in XeTeX/LuaTeX.

Comment: Also for em dash: `|`

Answer (score 92):

The latex commands are:

- Hyphen: `-`
- En-dash: `\textendash`
- Em-dash: `\textemdash`

With the latter two, you will likely want to append `{}`, because they swallow following space.

If you want to use the ligatures `--` and `---` with standard unicode fonts, use:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
% and/or - see comments
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
```

This will emulate substitution of unicode characters for certain "latex standard" ligatures which are present as ordinary unicode characters in modern fonts.

Comment: It's preferable to use the `Ligatures=TeX` version, which works both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, while the other (older) version can't be interpreted by LuaLaTeX. The option can also be used when defining a specific font with `\setmainfont`, `\newfontfamily` and similar commands; it's not necessary to use `\defaultfontfeatures`. If one uses it, probably a declaration `\setmonofont` should go *before* `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}`.

Comment: Question to anyone following this thread. Are there any known package clashes? I have ``\usepackage{fontspec}`` with ``\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}`` with ``\usepackage{libertine}`` and I compile with ``XeLaTeX`` and I don't get the ``---`` emdash effect at all. I'm considering asking a separate question, but perhaps I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: package clash with ``\usepackage{xesearch}`` apparently...

Comment: @PatrickT Right, hence why I include the official latex commands.

Comment: `! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.` - FWIW

Answer (score 15):

In some contexts it is appropriate to put thin spaces around an em dash, e.g., `\,---\,`. I defer to the Chicago Manual of Style and Bringhurst on typography for more.

Comment: I use full on spaces, like `{ }---{ }`.

Answer (score 2):

I used the command to achieve long dash

```
\textemdash
```

For example:

```
2021 \textemdash \ The Capability of Wavelet Convolutional Neural Network for Detecting Cyber Attack of Distributed Denial of Service in Smart Grid, ICCWAMTIP, (EI)
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this already covered by Marcin's answer?