# Double minus sign not changing to long sign when using XeLaTeX system font

Tags: fontspec

Normally I often use the sign `--` to display a long minus sign `—` in my text. However, after using the fontspec package and setting my main font to "HelveticaNeue" the long minus sign isn't displayed anymore, but the two minus signs theirselves. Is there any possibility to change that behavior? Thanks for any hint.

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.9]{HelveticaNeue}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
This is some text -- this is some other text. %not showing endash
\end{document}
```

Comment: @OliverBorchert -- `\endash` probably shouldn't work in math, but if it doesn't work in text, then there's a bug.

Comment: You probably have an older version of `fontspec`. The most recent one enables `Ligatures=TeX` by default.

Comment: @OliverBorchert try putting `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}` right after `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: @erik Great, this works! Thank you all for your fast and very helpful replies! :)

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much, just updated and working perfectly now ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the LaTeX command for “em dash” (—)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53413/24974)

Comment: @erik -- the comment about `\defaultfontfeatures` looks like an answer.  i didn't see that this was present in the question you mention as a possible duplicate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It wasn't in the question specifically, but it appears in one of the answers (not the accepted one, though). Should I link to the answer instead?

Comment: @erik -- yes, linking to the answer would make it easier to find what is needed.  even with the link (and possible acceptance as duplicate), a brief answer here could be helpful to someone else with the same problem.