# Is \endash an obsolete command?

Tags: obsolete

So, through the years, I have an on and off user of TeX. Although I have master some things in the past, I find myself to re-read books at the Introductory level.
Recently, I have started reading Marc van Dongen's "LaTeX and Friends" introductory book. This was published in 2012 I presume.

Now, as I progressed in my reading, I have found that some of the commands in the text are not recognized by my LaTeX Distribution: I am using texlive on a Windows 10 64-bit Laptop and writing with Texmaker as the editor.
For instance, here is a screenshot:
[image: simple bibliography]

As you can see the command `\endash`above was not recognized and I got an error. After much googling, I found that `\textendash`is the working alternative. This is a code snippet from a book that was published 12 years ago yet my LaTeX distribution cannot typeset the code from it. I have tried to look at Esenbach and Trettin's [l2tabu](https://mirror.ufs.ac.za/ctan/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf) which sums up a list of deprecated commands and packages and suggests the newer versions. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything related to the `\endash` command.
Now I am wondering if there is a list of obsolete commands that I should be aware of (other than `l2tabu` obviously).

Comment: They may have defined `\newcommand{\endash}{--}`, or included another package that defined it.

Comment: Related: [What is the LaTeX command for "em dash" (—)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53413/5764); [Dashes: - vs. – vs. —](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3819/5764)

Comment: Makes complete sense about the defining a new command. I was starting to think I was missing something bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LaTeX command is `\textendash`.

`\endash` is not defined by any packages in common general use that I know. It may be the book was using a local package that defined this, or as it is simply a typeset example in a book, it may be that it never related to running code at all.

On the other hand, the LaTeX class used for TUGBoat, the proceedings of the TeX User group, `ltugboat.cls`, does define `\def\endash{--}` so it's possible that this originated in a tugboat article and picked up local definitions from there.

`

Comment: Not a bad theory. Just begs the question, who'd rather write `\endash` than simply use `--` ? :-)

Comment: @Ingmar people who find `\textendash` too much to type?

Comment: I see. `\textendash` is too much, `--` is too little, so `\endash` it is. And why not? I'm a firm believer of the Goldilocks principle myself, at times, and there should always be more than one way to skin the cat.

Comment: @Ingmar And direct input: `‒  –  —`. ;)