# how to print -- in Latex

Tags: pdftex

How to output `--` in Latex. When I use it directly, it will only show a `-`.
I added transliterated characters in front, but they all reported errors.

When I put it in a mathematical environment, it becomes `lscpu − −extend`.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_155.html#:~:text=If%20you%20simply%20want%20the,%24%5Cbackslash%24%20in%20your%20file.  --  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters

Comment: Thank you! But the special characters on the website do not seem to contain -. Only underscore.

Comment: +1: FYI, this question is very related:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36692

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621751

\begin{document}

\Huge
\begin{itemize}
    \item -- (\texttt{-\,-}) % You do not want that.
    \item -\,- (\texttt{-\textbackslash,-}) % Maybe better.
    \item -\kern 0pt- (\texttt{-\textbackslash kern 0pt-}) % Maybe better.
\end{itemize}
% See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353
% and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53413.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update:** I found a related question: [How do I prevent LaTeX from creating en-dash and em-dash?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36692). Especially the answer of Werner seems to be suitable for your situation.

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks

Comment: @Yujie If the answer solved the problem then please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Then the Q&A format is completed.